# Brightness control not working after Power change

Tags: 16.04, laptop, power-management, screen, brightness

Everything was working fine until I tried to change the brightness once. Then whenever I plug in/out power to the laptop **Brightness of the screen sets to zero.**

I also tried to change the brightness from **System Settings/Brightness & Locks** but found out **No Slider there.**

I could only reset brightness manually by running

```
$ sudo su
# echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I tried to change **Dim screen to save power** option too but it did not affect anything.

Also the **Brightness control keys** do not work once power is changed.

Everything works as normal once I manually adjust the brightness to 150.

What is the problem?